# Postgresql data validation checks based on table values

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a database that tracks electrical cables.  Each cable contains 1 or more cores that are connected to terminals at each end.  The number of cores in each cable is defined in a table.

```
| number_of_cores  | cable_id
|----------2-------|---1-----|
```

The core table is as follows

```
cable_no   | from_id | core_mark | to_id
1001       |       1 | 1 Black   |     2
1001       |       2 | 1 White   |     4
```

I want to create a check that will prevent another 1001 cable core from being inserted.

Is this possible in postgresql?

Ideally, if I tried to insert another 1001 cable with another unique core number, the error would be something like "all cores used on cable 1001"

Thanks,

Comment: Does that mean you should have only 2 similar (cable_no) at the maximum?

Comment: Is the cable_id = 1001 in the first table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Jaisus gave a good answer.

I would add only a cross-check into the `cable` to prevent to set bad values into `number_of_cores`:

```
create or replace function test_cable_number_of_cores(in_cable_id int,in_number_of_cores int)
 returns boolean
 language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
    res boolean := false;
begin
    res := (in_number_of_cores>0 and (select count(cable_id) from core where cable_id=in_cable_id) <= in_number_of_cores);

    return res;
end;
$function$;


alter table cable add check(test_cable_number_of_cores(cable_id, number_of_cores));

-- ok
insert into cable(cable_id, number_of_cores) values (3, 2);
update cable set number_of_cores=3 where cable_id=3;

-- error
update cable set number_of_cores=1 where cable_id=1;
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you helping out.  I followed the steps for my version and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is something like a check constraint. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html)

Follow those steps :

**1. Create some table properly**

```
create table cable (cable_id int primary key, number_of_cores int);
create table core (core_id int primary key, cable_id int references cable (cable_id), from_id int, core_mark varchar (50), to_id int);
```

**2. Create the function that will verify the inserts**

```
create or replace function test_max_core_number(in_cable_id int)
 returns boolean
 language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
    res boolean := false;
begin
    if exists (
        select *
        from cable 
        where cable_id = in_cable_id
            and number_of_cores > (select count(*) from core where cable_id = in_cable_id )
    )
    then 
        res := true;
    end if;

    return res;
end;
$function$;
```

**3. Add the constraint to your table**

```
alter table core 
add constraint cstr_check check (test_max_core_number(cable_id));
```

**4. Now it is time for some testing :)**

```
insert into cable (cable_id, number_of_cores) values (1, 2), (2, 3);
insert into core (core_id, cable_id, from_id, core_mark, to_id)
values
    (1, 1, 1, '1 Black', 2)
    ,(2, 1, 2, '1 White', 4);
```

Normally all goes fine for now.

**5. And now the wanted error !**

```
insert into core (core_id, cable_id, from_id, core_mark, to_id)
values
    (3, 1, 3, '1 Green', 2);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: A good answer. I added my answer with a cross-check for `cable.number_of_cores`.